# Runtime grammar productions creation

Tags: python, django, nlp

I am interested in natural languge processing with python-django.

My project requires creation of grammar productions at runtime. That means, whenever i ask a question or write a sentence, basic nlp steps like pos-tagging should be done and get them added to grammar productions or any other structure ( even if the words are not present in grammar) , so that i can do the further chunking and extraction of different nouns, verbs ,etc separately from that grammar.

Please guide me the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't? What worked differently than you expected?

Comment: I was able to do the pos tagging, NP chunking, extraction of nouns. I wrote my own grammar for example: who is the actor in movie? My grammar consisted of N-> actor|movie, v->is, Det->who|the.. I got the required output also. But I want to not just limit this to my grammar productions alone. Even if i write random words (not present in grammar) i should be able to do the nlp processing. I wrote the grammar mainly since my input keywords may consist of hindi or marathi set of words too.

Answer (score 1):

[NLTK](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/) is the most popular python framework for NLP processing as I know it can do POS tagging, deep parsing, and allow you to write extraction rules based on those outputs.